# How can I parse this string into a cell array in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab, split, string-formatting, cell-array

I have a string:

```
sen = '0.31431 0.64431 Using drugs is not cool Speaker2';
```

I am trying to write code that will generate:

```
cell = {'0.31431','0.64431', 'Using drugs is not cool', 'Speaker2'};
```

The problem is that I don't want to use the number of words in `'Using drugs is not cool'` because these will change in other examples.

I tried:

```
output = sscanf(sen,'%s %s %c %Speaker%d');
```

But it doesn't work as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you will always have to remove the first two words and last word, collecting everything else together, then you can use [`strsplit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) and [`strjoin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html) as follows:

```
sen = '0.31431 0.64431 Using drugs is not cool Speaker2';
words = strsplit(sen);  % Split all words up
words = [words(1:2) {strjoin(words(3:end-1), ' ')} words(end)]  % Join words 3 to end-1

words =

  1×4 cell array

    '0.31431'    '0.64431'    'Using drugs is not cool'    'Speaker2'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp, but it's a bit ugly:

```
>> str = '0.31431 0.64431 Using drugs is not cool Speaker2';
>> regexp(str,'(\d+\.\d+)\s(\d+\.\d+)\s(.*?)\s(Speaker\d+)','tokens')

ans =

  1×1 cell array

    {1×4 cell}

>> ans{:}

ans =

  1×4 cell array

    {'0.31431'}    {'0.64431'}    {'Using drugs is not cool'}    {'Speaker2'}
```